# Counting Occurences of words in file

Tags: python, for-loop

Just a preface, I have read--far too many--of the posts here about the same topic, and none of them quite cover the specific guidelines I'm under. I'm supposed to create an algorithm that counts the occurrence of each word in a text file, and display each as such:
"The: 4
Jump: 2
Fox: 6".
The terms I'm under is to use the skills we learned in our beginner python class, which means we cannot use dictionary, counters, sets or lists. (basically anything that would help shorten our code, tbh). I'm not the best at python so I've been struggling... pretty hard, to say the least. The closest I've gotten was scrabbling my old notes together from my previous class and finding a demo code that I reformatted.

```
wordsinlist = "words.txt"
word=input("Enter word to be searched:")
count = 0
 
with open("words.txt", 'r') as wordlist:
    for line in wordlist:
        words = line.split()
        for i in words:
            if(i==word):
                count=count+1
print("Occurrences of the word:")
print(count)
```

The issue with this is that I need my code to display all of the words and their occurences at once, with no search input. There's definitely a way to do this, but I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed, and I've been going at it for like 5 hours now haha.
It definitely needs to look a little closer to this:

```
#Output
The: 112
History: 29
Learning: 25
```

Any help or hints are much appreciated! Thank you in advance! I know its a dumb question, these online classes are really frustrating.

Comment: "cannot use dictionary, counters, sets or lists" - is this even possible? Even a basic approach would require a list of words of some form.

Comment: Is `count=count+1` not a counter? Not using dicts, lists, or counting variables sure makes this sound like asking somebody to swim without water in the pool.

Answer (score 0):

without lists (or similar) I think is impossible...probably you're allowed to use lists , that is basic python!!

If you need to count the occurrance of all words, you don't need to insert them with input method, right?

So this is one simple solution:

```
with open("words.txt", 'r') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    lines_1 = [element.strip() for element in lines]
    lines_2 = list(set(lines_1))
    for w in lines_2:
        for l in lines_1:
            if(l==w):
                count=count+1
        print("Occurrences of {} : {}".format(w,count))
        count = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Unfortunately I'm not allowed to use sets either. This entire project is apparently made just to make me suffer haha.